# src of dynamicly generated image is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome

I have an HTML block I create dynamically. I cannot get the `src` property of an image inside this block.

The following are the properties from the Chrome developer console:

```
typeof(image)
"object"

image.html()
"<img src="../images/icons/quickshare/enabled/accounting/abacus_48.png">"

image.src
undefined

image.attr("src")
undefined

image.prop("src")
undefined
```

As you can see, the HTML of the `image` object has the correct content, but I cannot access the `src` property. What could be the cause?

Comment: How do you get `image`, how do you set the `src`, why are the quotes stranges on your posted HTML?

Comment: @RC.: The quotes are strange (probably) because the dev console prints strings in quotes, even if they have quotes in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's the HTML (`html()` returns `innerHTML`), you currently have the parent element of the image

try

```
image.find('img').prop('src')
```

Comment: That seems to be right. gosh. That one confused me a long time:D

Comment: @OleAlbers - no problem, the html() call gives it away, it should return the inner contents of the element, not the outer tags, hence you must currently have a parent element.